# servlet stores list in servlet context

Tags: java, servlets

Moment the main servlet is deployed, it needs to perform calculations and prepare a list. this list needs to be accessed by the other servlet which are called subsequently. the calculation needs to run only once. could some one please explain how to go about doing that.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and perform calculation from there.

---

The class file :

```
public final class YourListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
        //Calculation goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        //Nothing to do
    }
}
```

web.xml :

```
<web-app>
    <!-- ... -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>ext.company.project.listener.YourListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- ... -->
</wep-app>
```

Alternatively, instead of that entry in web.xml file, you can annotate your `ServletContextListener` class with `@WebListener` in later versions of the Servlet spec. The Servlet container will automatically detect, load, and execute your listener class.

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - Servlet Life Cycle](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html)

Comment: thanks Colin. But i perform the calculation and then how do i store/retrieve it...please explain

Comment: @Abdul, you can store the result in your [context](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) as an attribute and load it later with `getServletContext().getAttribute()` from any servlet

Comment: @Colin... thank you so much for the help. to use this context object, do I need to call the request dispatcher using the context? please let me know

Comment: @Abdul, This context is the servlet context. Accessible from any servlet with `getServletContext()` and from `YourListener` in `event.getServletContext()`.

Comment: @Colin...and the moment i have done this, the server fails the load. It just says GLassFish server domain failed to load

Comment: oh..i am not allowed to type over 600 characters..how do i post the code

Comment: public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        try {
            System.out.println("Server int in listener Successfully");
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            System.out.println("Using the connection pool");
             dataSource = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/myDatasource");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

Comment: BuildRdLinkList getBuild = new BuildRdLinkList(dataSource);
     ArrayList<Nodelist> roadlink;

  try
  {
   roadlink = getBuild.getNetworkWhp();
   context.setAttribute("roadLink", roadlink);
  }

Comment: the server starts performing the calculation and after a few seconds crashes without stating error except for Personal Domain GlassFish error

Comment: okay. Just try to remove the content of `contextInitialized` too see if it isn't the added code which is causing the error.

Comment: i tried doing that ...it still fails...the list calculation takes about 60-70 seconds totally.... but now the server crashes after 20-30 secs

Comment: @Abdul did you removed everything ? There shouldn't be any error.

Comment: yes i removed everything. just put the buildlink list class and its function. does the servletcontextlistener have any kind of time out or something?

Comment: Well.. i just removed the entire thing and put it on a tomcat server and it worked great..thanks Colin!

Answer (score 0):

in your main servlet initialization method

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);

    // do calculations
    ArrayList resultsList = calculate_something();

    // save for other servlets
    config.getServletContext().setAttribute("SAVED_DATA", resultsList);
}
```

in the other servlets

```
// retrieving value from ServletContext
ArrayList list = (ArrayList)getServletContext().getAttribute("SAVED_DATA");
```

Comment: If the servlet is destroyed and reloaded this will happen twice.

Comment: @Colin Hebert you are correct, he mentioned that the main servlet needed to do the calculation, that is why I posted what I did. It is obvious from the exchange that is misunderstood the question.